# How to get the size of child view in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to get the size of a child view in react native. I have a component that should adjust its size according to its child view with some additional space.
It is important to get the height and width of child view, I don't want to use flexes.
Thank you

Comment: `I want to get the size of child view in react native` ok, can you show us what you tried? If you have issues, post specific questions and we can try and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As provided by the docs of View of react native :
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view

You can use onLayout event for getting the size of a view. For example:

```
<View onLayout={this.onLayout}>
    ...
</View>
```

If you want to get the size from subview to parent. Just simply pass your onLayout function to your child view. And use the below instead:

**Parent class:**

```
<View>
    <B onLayout={this.onLayout} />
</View>
```

**Child "B" class:**

```
<View onLayout={this.props.onLayout}>
    ...
</View>
```